# Android Navigation Drawer onItemClick position 0 is never read

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, baseadapter

This is how my navigation drawer looks like:

[image]

So technically position of Home = 0, Housekeeping = 1...so on

However when I click Home, the position returned in the onItemClick is 1 and it opens the Housekeeping activity. Same thing happens when I click Housekeeping, it opens Laundry. So it returns the position as = clicked position + 1.

Here is the code for my BaseActivity (which is extended by other activites who want to use Navigation Drawer)

```
public class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    protected FrameLayout frameLayout;
    protected ListView mDrawerList;
    protected String[] navItemsTitles = {"Home","Housekeeping","Laundry","Food","Reservations","Concierge","Hotel Info"};
    protected ArrayList<Items> navItemsArray;
    protected static int position;
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private static boolean isLaunched = true;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle actionBarDrawerToggle;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.base_layout);

        frameLayout = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.content_frame);
        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);

        navItemsArray = new ArrayList<Items>();

        Log.i("NAV", "---- navItemsTitles: " + Arrays.toString(navItemsTitles));

        navItemsArray.add(new Items("Home", R.drawable.home_icon));
        navItemsArray.add(new Items("Housekeeping", R.drawable.housekeeping_icon));
        navItemsArray.add(new Items("Laundry", R.drawable.laundry_icon));
        navItemsArray.add(new Items("Food", R.drawable.food_icon));
        navItemsArray.add(new Items("Reservations", R.drawable.reservation_icon));
        navItemsArray.add(new Items("Concierge", R.drawable.concierge_icon));
        navItemsArray.add(new Items("Hotel Info", R.drawable.info_icon));

        //Adding header on list view
        View header = (View) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.list_view_header_layout, null);
        mDrawerList.addHeaderView(header);

        // Set the adapter for the list view
        mDrawerList.setAdapter(new NavigationDrawerListAdapter(this, navItemsArray));

        //Set the list's on-item click listener
        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {
                Log.i("NAV", "---------- onItemClick position: " + position);
                openActivity(position);
            }
        });

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.mipmap.ic_launcher_round);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        actionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this,
                mDrawerLayout,
                R.string.open_drawer,
                R.string.close_drawer
        ) {
            @Override
            public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
                Log.i("NAV", "---- onDrawerClosed position: " + position);
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle(navItemsTitles[position]);
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
                super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
            }

            @Override
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle(getString(R.string.app_name));
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
                super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
            }

            @Override
            public void onDrawerSlide(View drawerView, float slideOffset) {
                super.onDrawerSlide(drawerView, slideOffset);
            }

            @Override
            public void onDrawerStateChanged(int newState) {
                super.onDrawerStateChanged(newState);
            }
        };

        mDrawerLayout.addDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle);


    }

    protected void openActivity(int position) {
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);

        BaseActivity.position = position;

        Log.i("NAV", "------ Selected Item Position::"+position);

        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                startActivity(new Intent(BaseActivity.this, HomeActivity.class));
                break;
            case 1:
                startActivity(new Intent(BaseActivity.this, HousekeepingActivity.class));
                break;
            case 2:
                startActivity(new Intent(BaseActivity.this, LaundryActivity.class));
                break;
            case 3:
                startActivity(new Intent(BaseActivity.this, FoodActivity.class));
                break;
            case 4:
                startActivity(new Intent(BaseActivity.this, ReservationsActivity.class));
                break;
            case 5:
                startActivity(new Intent(BaseActivity.this, ConciergeActivity.class));
                break;
            case 6:
                startActivity(new Intent(BaseActivity.this, HotelInfoActivity.class));
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        //code
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
        //code
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        //code
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        //code
    }
}
```

This is the info from Logcat:

```
I: ---- navItemsTitles: [Home, Housekeeping, Laundry, Food, Reservations, Concierge, Hotel Info] 
I: ---------- onItemClick position: 1 
I: ------ Selected Item Position::1 
I: ---- navItemsTitles: [Home, Housekeeping, Laundry, Food, Reservations, Concierge, Hotel Info]
```

Here is my NavigationDrawerListAdapter

```
public class NavigationDrawerListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<Items> itemsArray;

    public NavigationDrawerListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Items> itemsArray) {
        this.context = context;
        this.itemsArray = itemsArray;
    }

    private class ViewHolder {
        TextView itemName;
        ImageView itemIcon;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return itemsArray.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return itemsArray.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder = null;

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if(convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.drawer_list_item, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();

            holder.itemName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.item_name_txtview);
            holder.itemIcon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.item_icon_imgview);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        Items item = (Items) getItem(position);
        holder.itemName.setText(item.getItemName());
        holder.itemIcon.setBackgroundResource((int)item.getIconId());

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong? All the items come in as given, so everyone is at their right position, but when 1st item (at position 0) is clicked, it returns position == 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have to set headerview on drawer menu that time header is only 0th position. so your home menu return only 1st position.

so you have to change like this

```
switch (position) {
            case 1:
                startActivity(new Intent(BaseActivity.this, HomeActivity.class));
                break;
            case 2:
                startActivity(new Intent(BaseActivity.this, HousekeepingActivity.class));
                break;
            case 3:
                startActivity(new Intent(BaseActivity.this, LaundryActivity.class));
                break;
            case 4:
                startActivity(new Intent(BaseActivity.this, FoodActivity.class));
                break;
            case 5:
                startActivity(new Intent(BaseActivity.this, ReservationsActivity.class));
                break;
            case 6:
                startActivity(new Intent(BaseActivity.this, ConciergeActivity.class));
                break;
            case 7:
                startActivity(new Intent(BaseActivity.this, HotelInfoActivity.class));
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
```

Comment: So you mean to say that the topmost header - with the round icon and name is considered as position 0?

Comment: Yes, User icon and name as position 0, Home icon is 1st position

Comment: But its a headerView, why would it get counted as one of the list items? I have explicitly added it as a header.

Comment: Its a android default documentary, while you add header, header is consider in 0th position, otherwise 1st menu item is consider 0th position.

Answer (score 1):

@codeinprogress give a try on this line of code

```
mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {
                Log.i("NAV", "---------- onItemClick position: " + position);
                **openActivity(position-1);**
            }
        });
```

Comment: replace it same as it is and give a try

Comment: Yes, it works. As @Raja below explained that the headerView is counted as 0. My only question is why? Isn't it defined as header? SO why is it counted as a part of other items?

Comment: Yes it did. Thanks.